# Gostaria de extrair hora,minuto e segundo do Timestamp [Pyspark]

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, ipython-notebook, spark

Para extrair data e hora no pyspark, estou utilizando essa função, pois, já me traz no UTC correto.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn('teste',F.current_timestamp()).show()
```

Mas ela me traz data e hora, e gostaria somente da hora, será que tem como manipular, ou existe alguma outra função que me traga somente a Hora,minuto e segundo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma coluna com valores timestamp e utilizar as funções de hora, minuto e segundo:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
   .withColumn('hora', F.hour('timestamp'))
   .withColumn('minutos', F.minute('timestamp'))
   .withColumn('segundos', F.second('timestamp')))
```

Exemplo de saída:

| timestamp | hora | minutos | segundos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-08T21:27:41.722+0000 | 21 | 27 | 41 |
| 2022-02-08T21:27:41.722+0000 | 21 | 27 | 41 |
| 2022-02-08T21:27:41.722+0000 | 21 | 27 | 41 |
| 2022-02-08T21:27:41.722+0000 | 21 | 27 | 41 |